# Json File in Python - output summary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm getting a json file in python 3 and have to sort it. I did all that correctly, but it won't print into the output file.

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
#Source - youtube.com/thenewboston - Bucky Roberts

# load data from json file
with open('makes.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# dictionary to hold items
countries_makes = defaultdict(int)
countries_common = defaultdict(int)

# loop through data (json object with data in an array 'Makes')
for m in data['Makes']:
    # grab the country
    country = m['make_country']
    countries_makes[country] += 1
    is_common = int(m['make_is_common'])
    countries_common[country] += is_common

# put data in a list
result = []
for c in countries_makes:
    # each item in the list will contain: (country, makes, common)
    result.append((c, countries_makes[c], countries_common[c]))

# sort result list by make in reverse order
result.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

# create output file with headers and rows
with open('summary.csv', 'wb') as f:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f)
    csv.writerow(['Country', 'Makes', 'Common'])
    csv_output.writerows(result)

print('done, see results in summary.csv')
```

So how do I make this work? Problem with the with open lines at the end.

I need to open summary.csv to finish it.

Comment: What do you mean "won't print in the output file"? The CSV output file is blank? Have you checked that `result` is not empty? What does your data look like?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error I believe. I ran it and had to fix line 35 of your code.

```
csv.writerow() -> csv_output.writerow()
```

Based on the keys, I used this data:

```
{"Makes":[{"make_country":"countryA", "make_is_common":1}]}
```

Fix your code to be:

```
# create output file with headers and rows
with open('summary.csv', 'wb') as f:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f)
    csv_output.writerow(['Country', 'Makes', 'Common'])
    csv_output.writerows(result)
```

Produced:

```
$ cat summary.csv 
Country,Makes,Common
countryA,1,1
```

Comment: If this fixed your problem, please mark it as the solution.